# Загрузчик скриптов javascript (или ресурсов вообще) на JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте!
Меня интересует **JavaScript**-загрузчик - то есть скрипт загружающий другие *javascript* с сервера.
То есть что бы не прописывать все скрипты по одному в ресурсах страницы, а прописать один и сказать ему какие ещё скрипты нужно загрузить с сервера... А после загрузки всех скриптов сгенерировать специальное событие говорящее о полной загрузки скриптов.
Это нужно для того что бы скрипты грузились в нужном порядке, а так же для установки факта загрузки всех скриптов.

Если есть готовое решение - отлично, а если его нет и кто-то подскажет (желательно с наброском) как такой загрузчик написать - буду очень признателен!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для использования с ExtJs целесообразно использовать Ext.Loader. Раскладываете все ваши классы по файлам и потом загрузчик сам загрузит всё необходимое. [Пример использования](http://www.sencha.com/blog/using-ext-loader-for-your-application/)

Для общего случая вам подойдёт:

- [**HeadJS**](http://headjs.com/)  - весьма удобная штука, умеет загружать и js и css
- [**LABjs**](http://labjs.com/)
- [JSL](http://www.andresvidal.com/jsl)
- [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/)
- и т.д. ([сравнительная таблица](https://spreadsheets.google.com/lv?key=tDdcrv9wNQRCNCRCflWxhYQ))