# Как можно грузить скрипт через  Ajax?

Tags: ajax, javascript

Привет. Как загрузить и отследить, что он загрузился?

Comment: кому ще интересно http://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/include-javascript-file-inside-javascript-file

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Для этого можно использовать много разных методов. Например такой (с использованием jquery):

```
$.getScript('ajax/scripts/somescript.js', function() {
    // выполняется после загрузки скрипта
    alert('Вот уже и загрузился!');
});
```

Без использования сторонних библиотек:

```
function loadScript(src, callback) {
    var scriptTag = document.createElement("script")
    scriptTag.type = "text/javascript";
    if(scriptTag.readyState) {
        //IE
        scriptTag.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (scriptTag.readyState == "loaded" ||
            scriptTag.readyState == "complete") {
                scriptTag.onreadystatechange = null;
                setTimeout(function(){scriptTag.parentNode.removeChild(scriptTag)},1)
                callback();
            }
        };
    }else{
        //Others
        scriptTag.onload = function() {
            setTimeout(function(){
                scriptTag.parentNode.removeChild(scriptTag)},1
            )           
            callback();
        };
    }
    scriptTag.src = src;
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(scriptTag);
}

// Использование
loadScript('scripts/mouse.js', function(){
    // выполняется после загрузки скрипта
    alert('Вот уже и загрузился!');
});
```

(Взято [отсюда](http://snipplr.com/view/18608/javascript-simple-script-loader/))

Также, почитайте [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/185332#185335). Там есть ссылки на другие библиотеки для загрузки скриптов.

Comment: почему у вас везде scriptTag ? и если элемент сначала вставить в head  то onload так-же работает (хотя последнее я не проверял - негде).

Comment: Простите, скопипастил не глядя. Там таки `script`

Comment: $.getScript работает отлично ,а вот второй пример нет,хотя фаербаг ошибок не пишет.Спасибо Вам за потраченое время.

Answer (score 3):

Точно так же, как и любой другой контент, который грузится через AJAX:

```
var req = new XmlHttpRequest();
req.open('GET', url, true);
req.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (req.readySatae == 4 && req.status == 200) {
       // загрузилось! принятые данные - в req.responseText
    }
}
req.send(null);
```